# Laravel 5.5, Default route for index not working for resource controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a resource Controller named CmsPagesController,

```
class CmsPagesController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return 'something';
    // $pages=CmsPages::all();        
    // return view('backend.pages.cms.list')->with('pages',$pages);
}

public function list(){
    return '123';
}
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('backend.pages.cms.add');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'      =>      'required',
        'slug'      =>  'required',
        'description'=> 'required'            
    ]);

    $Page=new CmsPages;
    $Page->name= $request->input('name');
    $Page->slug= $request->input('slug');
    $Page->description= $request->input('description');
    $Page->copyright= $request->input('copyright');
    $Page->keywords= $request->input('keywords');


    $Page->save();

    return redirect('/admin/pages')->with('success','Page Added Successfully');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

My Add function and store function is working perfect, I can render add page and can store data to database but my index function is not working, I have placed a sample return statement but that is not executed as well. what am I missing

Following is my route

```
 Route::resource('pages','CmsPagesController');
```

Comment: Please share your route as well. What is the url you visit to view the index action response? Do you get 404? What is the output of the get request?

Comment: Updated @HilmiErdemKEREN and have added my route

Comment: Please run php artisan route::list and make sure you see your route in there. Also can you please share the error you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, that is index function wasn't returning anything, not even any error.

I had a UsersController made as a resource.

And route as:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

When you try to hit the following URL

> ...public/users/index

it won't return anything.

It worked for me when I tried

> ...public/users

the index function is automatically called. You don't have have to write /index in the the url.